# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import with Jest + react-native-animated-ellipsis

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jestjs, react-animated

My snapshot test is failing with react-native. I have followed few solutions but nothing worked. 
Error I am facing is:

> /Users/USER_NAME/Projects/project_name/node_modules/react-native-animated-ellipsis/dist/AnimatedEllipsis.js:1
>       (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
>                                                                     ^^^^^^
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>
> ```
>   at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:178:20
> ```

In my `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "Tests/Setup.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|rent-react-native|react-native-navigation|react-native-vector-icons|react-native-maps|react-native-animated-ellipsis)/)"
    ]
  },
```

and `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "react-native"],
      "plugins": ["react-native-animated-ellipsis"],
      "only": [
        "./**/*.js",
        "node_modules/react-native-animated-ellipsis"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We're also having this exact issue. Excluding other packages via `transformIgnorePatterns` seemed to work but not `react-native-animated-ellipsis`

Comment: Solved this by just copying the component from the repo and putting it directly into our project. The repo seems pretty stale and I didn't bother asking them to fix their `dist` folder to be es5 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd like to apply a babel transformation on one of your project's dependency but following the error message, even if you wanna apply a babel transform on react-native-animated-ellipsis, you should probably do it on the src and exclude the dist folder.